# Controller is not returning any type of data when called except for a test string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am connecting to a 3rd party API that requires calls to retrieve an authorization code and a token.

The API requires a redirect URL, which when returned, contains the authorization code attached to the query string.

So, on my side so I set up this controller below that will read the queryString.

Then, my app needs to fire a POST request to the API to get the token, and you will see me calling the controller the contains the POST request.

When I click my button to connect to the API, in my browser window, I do see that I am redirected to the GetGeologicalPeriod() controller below because I see the message:

> you have reached the GeologicalPeriod endpoint.

And I do see the authorization code in the query string.
But I don't see anything else, no errors, nothing.

I was expecting to see the results retuned from the call to GetGeologicalPeriodToken, or at least an error that it failed, but I am getting nothing...not even in the browser console window.

So I am kind of at a loss as to what is actually happening.

Since this is on a development server, I can't step through it locally in Visual Studio.

Is there anyway to show messages or write to console so I can see what's going on?

Thanks!

```
   [ApiController]
public class GeologicalPeriodController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<String> GetGeologicalPeriod()
    {
        string getTest = "you have reached the GeologicalPeriod endpoint.";
        var queryString = Request.Query["code"];
        var postResult = GetGeologicalPeriodToken(queryString);
        return postResult;
    }


    [HttpPost("AuthRequest")]
    public ActionResult<String> GetGeologicalPeriodToken(string authCode)
    {
        string authToken = authCode;
        string authString = "admin";

        var queryString = Request.Query["code"];
        var client = new RestClient("https://geologicalPeriod.geo.gov/oauth/token?accessType=professor&code=" + authCode + "&redirect_uri=https://jamaica.round.astro.edu/api/geologicalPeriodauth/geologicalPeriod/AuthRequest");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", authString);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var apiResponse = response;
        return apiResponse.Content.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: When `GetGeologicalPeriod()` finishes, your browser (if accessing through one) should show you a string with the content of the response retrieved from the server, *assuming the response had content*. Two things you could do: return `apiResponse.StatusCode` (or however the property is called) as well as the content, and check the HTTP response for `GetGeologicalPeriod()` - if everything is OK, when it finishes you should get HTTP 200

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it seems strange because I do see my test string `you have reached the GeologicalPeriod endpoint.` in the browser window but nothing else.  No errors and nothing in the console either.

Comment: Then the code you posted is not the correct one, because `getTest` is not printed anywhere at all in the current code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm sorry, I should have meant that I took it out when testing the actually process, but returned the `getTest` to make sure that the browser is being redirected to the proper URL path. sorry :)

Comment: But... the moment you return `"you have reached the GeologicalPeriod endpoint."`, the process has finished already and everything *should be* good. I am not sure I understand the question then

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I mean when I don't return the test string, and instead use `return postResult;`, which is made from, `GetGeologicalPeriodToken(queryString);`  I don't see anything in the browser window or console.

Comment: Ok, so my first comment still stands: two things you could do: return apiResponse.StatusCode (or however the property is called) as well as the content, and check the HTTP response for GetGeologicalPeriod() - if everything is OK, when it finishes you should get HTTP 200 (look at the Network tab)